# CI 3 failed to save a view into string variable

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

In CI2, we can pass a view to a variable
like this on my controller.

```
public function menu_repair_estim{

  $html = $this->load->view('v_rep_estim');
  echo $_html;
}
```

**ON, view**
to debug it, just `<p>This is te hompage<p>`
So, assumed when user click an anchor to `anchor('/menu_rep_estim','menu_home', array('id' => 'menu_home'))` it will be catch by jquery like this

```
$('#menu_rep_estim').live("click", function() {
        var this_url = $(this).attr("href");

        $.post(this_url, {}, function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

then, in master_page will be refresh just on the content.
But in CI3 , it gives me error like this:

```
Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string
```

Any help, it so appriciated

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```
public function menu_repair_estim{

  $html = $this->load->view('v_rep_estim',"",true);
  echo $_html;
}
```

First parameter -> view name

second parameter -> data to view,

Third parameter -> if true(get the view as string to a variable), if false(render view to browser)

Read [CI Docs](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data) here.

Answer (score 1):

For put view page into variable, you must pass 3 arguments in `view` function.

```
public function menu_repair_estim{

    $data['rows']=''; # Here you can pass your records
    $html = $this->load->view('v_rep_estim',$data,true);
    echo $html;
}
```

First argument of `view` function should be name of your `view page` and second argument should be your `records` or `data` and last argument must be `true`